# Access custom XML attributes from root element

Tags: java, android, xml

I have extended ViewGroup and created a custom Layout class in Android. I also have some custom XML attributes defined to help position subviews. I need to access a couple of the custom xml attributes (custom:view_height and custom:view_width) on the root XML element (the custom Layout) but when I try to access them from the Layout java class the TypedArray is null, it's like it cannot see them. They work fine on the child views. Any thoughts as to how I can access the custom XML attributes from up in the root? Thanks!

See code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package.of.my.CustomLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                        xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:orientation="vertical"
                                        android:background="@drawable/homecell_selector"
                                        custom:view_width="400"   // I need this!!
                                        custom:view_height="200"  // I need this!!
                                        >

<Button android:id="@+id/postText" android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                                      android:layout_marginTop="45dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                      android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:alpha="1"
                                      android:background="@color/HEX_FFFFFFFF" android:textColor="@color/HEX_000"
                                      android:textSize="15sp" android:visibility="visible" android:gravity="left"
                                      custom:view_width="0.87610022270753" 
                                      custom:eHeight="true"
                                      custom:view_height="0.44296926842493" 
                                      custom:eWidth="true"
                                      custom:originX="RIGHT" 
                                      custom:x="0.061399777292469"
                                      custom:eX="true" 
                                      custom:originY="BOTTOM"
                                      custom:y="0.1682145166653" 
                                      custom:eY="true"/>

<Button android:id="@+id/firstNameLastNameShortText" android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
                                      android:layout_marginTop="8dp" android:layout_height="18dp"
                                      android:layout_width="276dp" android:alpha="1"
                                      android:background="@color/HEX_2087fc" android:textColor="@color/HEX_000"
                                      android:textSize="15sp" android:visibility="visible" android:gravity="left"
                                      custom:view_width="0.86433765030597" 
                                      custom:eHeight="true"
                                      custom:view_height="0.15716154473749" 
                                      custom:eWidth="true"
                                      custom:originX="LEFT" 
                                      custom:x="0.065625" custom:eX="true"
                                      custom:originY="TOP" 
                                      custom:y="0.069849575438883"
                                      custom:eY="true"/>
</package.of.my.CustomLayout>
```

Comment: How are you attempting to access your custom attributes? Can you post the code?

Comment: `TypedArray properties = myContext.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, package.of.my.project.R.styleable.Custom);
view_height = properties.getFloat(package.of.my.project.R.styleable.Custom_view_height, view_height);`

but properties is empty.

Comment: Is the TypedArray null, as you say in the post, or does getFloat() return the default value? Also, are you calling this from the constructor for your CustomLayout or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need those. Because you need a width and a height. And whatever width and height you want to add to your custom view, you should add them directly to the android:layout_width and android:layout_height tags.

Comment: Thanks mike. Although I used a custom xml attributed called view_height and width, they are purely an arbitrary example. I understand you use the android:layout_height and width for that. Knowing this, is there any way you know of to access custom XML information from the root view? Thanks!